# contenteditable is triggering blur event when I click on it under firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, contenteditable

I have a contentEditable DIV

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

</div>
```

with the following javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var obj = {

        func1: function(){

            $("#content").on("click", function(){
                alert("click");
            });

            $("#content").on("blur", function(){
                alert("blur");
            });

        }

    }

    function execute(obj){

        obj.func1();

    }


    execute(obj);


});
```

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mody5/b84708c1/

The code is supposed to alert "click" when I click the contentEditable div and to alert "blur" when I click out of the contentEditable div, but in **FIREFOX** when I click it trigger "blur" event too !

Is this a bug ? how I can solve this ?

Comment: I think that's related to `alert()`, which probably triggers `blur()` in firefox.  If you use `console.log()` it's not happening

Comment: @itsgoingdown but in chrome it works fine! also if you remove contenteditable=true it will work in firefox without any problem !

Comment: @medBo it will "work" if you remove contenteditable because regular div elements don't have blur event..

Comment: @ShiranDror yes you're totally right. also if I change click with mousedown, it will work correctly, not sure why !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In firefox `alert()` will trigger the blur event, because it will change the focus into the alert box. And thus trigger the blur event.

In your code, just change `alert("click");` into something else.. like `console.log("click");`  and it will work.

Note: In chrome it works because the `alert()` function works in different ways for firefox and chrome.